# How to know about app launched and details jailbreak iOS 7

Tags: ios7, jailbreak, theos, tweak, springboard

I am making a tweak for **iOS 7**, in which I want to know about app launch event, and the details of app being launched (name and identifier). So far the only useful framework I have found is `SpringBoardServices.framework`. The header files which may be/are useful to track app launch event include:

- SBAppLaunchUtilities.h
- SBLaunchAppListener.h

If I am on right track, can anyone provide me information about their methods usage? There is no relevant information or guide present on `iphonedevwiki`.

Moreover, How can I get information about app launched? I have studied [Andy ibanez's](http://www.andyibanez.com/create-mobilesubstrate-tweaks-ios/) tutorial. It hooks `SBApplicationIcon` class, which I guess has been removed from iOS 7 frameworks because I can't find it in dumped frameworks. So what is alternate header? Is it `SBSCardItem.h` and `SBSCardItemsController` ?

Looking forward for help. Thanks.

Comment: SBApplicationIcon exists, but it's not part of SpringBoardServices. It is part of SpringBoard.app.

Comment: @AndyIbanez thanks alot for your reply. Can you please give me hint on how to use Springboard.app? Since private frameworks doesn't include one. Can I import it directly in my tweak file?

Comment: Yeah this is a crucial difference because people tend to think that SpringBoard is a framework when it's actually an app. The reason you don't always find it in private header dumps is because it isn't a framework. Some people have dumped it already (and don't forget you can dump it yourself). https://github.com/thomasfinch/iOS-7-SpringBoard-Headers

Comment: @AndyIbanez I didn't know that. Thanks for pointing it out. If Springboard.app exists, then there should be similar loads of other apps too, which I should discover. Right?

Comment: Yep, you can dump all the apps within. Messages, Calendar, Mail, just to name a few. I don't remember where they are stored in the file system, but they are also .apps, and have the known .app extension.

Comment: @AndyIbanez Ok. thanks a ton Andy. You made alot of things clear to me. You can write details in comments as answer, so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into `SpringBoard.app` instead of `SpringBoardServices.framework`. SpringBoard app comes "alone" because like it's extension implies, it's an app, and not a framework that can be found in the entire Private Frameworks.

You can get a lot of info from the `SBApplicationIcon` class in SpringBoard, such as the app display name and things like that. Check the headers for more info.