# I need to check if user open a facebook or whats app during driving

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, facebook

I need to crate app, one of it is features to check if user is using Facebook or whats App during driving is it doable.

Comment: We cant find as of now, refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35927006/6355922

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way. Even if iOS apps are allowed to fetch data from other apps, you have to make sure your app is running on background and checking. iOS manage memory itself and kills app in background automatically. So the app is not practical. Plus if you constantly check the speed in background, the battery life will decrease.

But again on the first hand as other answers, your app does not allowed to access data. So this is not doable.

Answer (score 2):

For privacy matters, Apple does not allow iOS apps to access other application's data, such as when the user enters them and other "sensitive" data of that sort. So, the simple answer is that you cannot do that. Another App's usage is undeterminable as of now on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible , as apple does not allow iOS Apps fetching or accessing other apps data. Thanks